# How to scroll the Windows 8 designer view in Visual Studio/Blend 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2013

When creating a Windows 8 app in Visual Studio 2013, I can create a page that does not fit entirely on the screen at any one time. I can easily flick the page from side to side when debugging; however, the VS Designer view seems to stick on the far left side of the page. What do I need to do to move this view from side to side along the page? I feel like this should be simple, but can't seem to find any Google results or UI cues.

If relevant, I am using C#/XAML.

Comment: I've found a solution at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcs3dxhe(v=vs.80).aspx which uses the document outline panel. Does anyone know of a solution that is quicker to access?